# how to make background for Horizontal Scroll view

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am trying to put some background color/picture behind the all Horizontal Scroll view - so that my pictures I putted there will be on back floating color
when I tried to define it (in xml) it got crazy and got spread all down the screen for some reason.. any 1 have an answer?

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_barcelona"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/barcelonah" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="|"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_berlin"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/berlinh" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="|"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_eilat"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/eilath" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="|"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: where did you gave background color/image in xml?

Comment: I tried everywhere ... HorizontalScrollView and both LinearLayout  and the same result